# Reference Not Working for Algorithm (MWE included)

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I am getting an error which I am not able to fix: referencing error of using an algorithm.

I have tried putting label both in and below the caption but I keep getting '??' error when I refr to the algorithm. I am working on overleaf so the example below can be tested online.

The Minimal Working Example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[algoruled,ruled,vlined,noend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{amsthm}   
\usepackage{cleveref}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
 \SetAlgoNoLine
 \SetNoFillComment
 \KwData{Something}
 \KwResult{Value}
 \For{i=1 to n}{
 T =  \underset{ A(S^{\textbackslash i}) } f[X[i]] 
  }
 \caption{My Algorithm}
 \label{algo:my_algo}
\end{algorithm}

\ref{algo:my_algo}

\end{document}
```

The algorithm is simplified to only keep the error-producing part: the error goes away if I delete the line:

```
 T =  \underset{ A(S^{\textbackslash i}) } f[X[i]]
```

But I cannot delete this line since it is the main part of the algorithm. Any possible way to avoid using hard reference here, when referring to the algorithm.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with missing references. Never ignore errors. `\underset` is only available in math-mode, so you need `$\udedrset{....}$`

Comment: Unrelated you should clean up your preamble and remove stuff that you don't use fx `latexsym` which is using an entire math alphabet for 9 symbols you probably don't use. Also always only include packages that are relevant to the problem you need help for.

Comment: I also have `! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.`

Comment: @tstseby, if there are errors chances are that the `.aux` file is not written or not correctly written, so you will have no automatic references at all. First thing first: make the code compile without errors.

Comment: As Rmano mentions, `amsthm` and `ntheorem` cannot be used in the same document. Who gave you this template? You are probably better of starting from stratch

Comment: The only relevant packages for this example are `amsmath`, `amssymb` and `algorithm2e` additionally it is not obvious what it is you want to do with this `\underset`. Additionally what is `textbackslash` here? As per the name this is for text, but `\underset` is a math construction where `\backslash` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @daleif putting \underset in math  model fixed the error, could you add it as an answer, so that i can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reduce the given MWE to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[algoruled,ruled,vlined,noend]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
 \SetAlgoNoLine
 \SetNoFillComment
 \KwData{Something}
 \KwResult{Value}
 \For{i=1 to n}{
 T = \underset{ A(S^{\textbackslash i}) } f[X[i]] 
  }
 \caption{My Algorithm}
 \label{algo:my_algo}
\end{algorithm}

\ref{algo:my_algo}

\end{document}
```

which gives the rather confusing error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.17  \caption
              {My Algorithm}
```

But `\underset` is a math construction so we probably need

```
$ T = \underset{ A(S^{\backslash i}) } f[X[i]] $
```

Note that I don't really know what you are trying to apply `\underset` on (it normally takes two arguments) since here it is only given one, it will add the stuff under `f`. Not sure if that is the intention. I also changes `\textbackslash` to `\blackslash` as the former is a text symbol and thus invalid in math mode.